# Pattern string matching between 0-1 and 4

Tags: java, regex, string

My string could be in the form like this:

"A3C10" or "A3B00" or "A3F90".

I want to return true if the string contains "A3" in the first two substring and "0" in the last substring index. Is there a way to write the regex pattern String matching here?

Comment: Yup, there is a way. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 6):

You can use regex for that:

```
string.matches("A3.*0");
```

It returns true, if string begins with `"A3"` and ends with `"0"`.

Answer (score 4):

Following on from Andronicus' answer, `.*` will match any sequence, so as long as it begins with `A3` and ends with `0` it will return true.

If you want to match the exact pattern of `A3XX0` where X is any character, then use the below pattern.

```
string.matches("A3..0");
```